# Laravel create first record with Bcrypt password

Tags: laravel, database, migration, bcrypt

Can i create the first record in the database via migration, where in the `password`column it is already bcrypted

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('level');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    User::firstOrCreate([
        'name' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'admin@app.com',
        'level' => 'Administrator',
        'password' => 'password'
    ]);
}
```

the code is working but the `password` is not encrypted, any suggestion ?

Comment: you would have to hash it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save password in this way:

```
    'password' => Hash::make('password');
```

Or you can use this way:

```
'password' => bcrypt('password');
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow the pattern, **it would be nice** to create the first record in the database in a seed and not in the migration.

Comment: this seems like it would be a comment, not an answer